# wxpython 3 on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

How can I download wxPython 3 on windows? 
I see [this](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/) link but it has .egg extension, and not exe. Ive given up on pyQT because of the lack of advanced tutorials for PyQT4, and I really would like a good libaray i can build GUI's from in Python. Ive read that wxpython 3 is compatible with the wxpython 2 api.

I cant find any good online tutorials for installation. Im using Python 3.3.2, Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: you should use easy_install. Check [this](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/654938-there-standard-way-install-egg-files-under-windows). egg files are actually zip files. So you can try unzipping it directly to your site-packages directory

Answer (score 0):

wxPython does not yet officially support Python 3. However, if you unpack the `.tar.gz` in a directory and run `c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py install` or equivalent on your system, it should install just fine.

However, beware that some parts of the library may not work on Python 3 yet.

*Note:* Tested with `wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.1.dev75711.tar.gz`.

Comment: ooh sorry, i want to write all the code myself from scratch. in this case, i should stick to pyqt then. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Your comment does not make any sense to me. Can you explain? You want to write all the code from scratch and ask for GUI designer?

Comment: Then the note about GUI designer does not apply.

Comment: This question is about wxPython. Joining the chat and asking there about PyQT tutorials makes more sense as this is opinionated question. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Answer (score 0):

To install wxPython for py3k (Phoenix) on windows.

- First install [setuptools](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools).
  This creates `easy_install.exe` in your Python Scripts folder.
- Then download [Phoenix](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/).
  For example: `wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.1.dev75783-py3.3-win32.egg`
- Put the downloaded egg file somewhere.
  For example in `C:\Python33\`
- Open the console, go to `C:\Python33\Scripts`

run:

```
C:\Python33\Scripts>easy_install.exe C:\Python33\wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.1.dev75783-py3.3-win32.egg
```

Phoenix will install